# NOT IN for multi field DQL Doctrine2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I just want to know how to do something like this in doctrine2

```
select 
    e 
from 
    \Entity e 
where 
    e.field1, e.field2 NOT IN (select e2.field1, e2.field2 from \Entity e2 where condition )
```

When I do this or I surround the two fields with parenthesis I got an error like:

> QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 136: Error: Expected
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','

or:

> QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 135: Error: Expected =, <,
>   <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got ','

PHP code:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery('
  SELECT r FROM LibrairieBundle\Entity\Reseau r 
  WHERE ( r.client1 = :me or r.client2 = :me ) and r.confirme = 1 
  and (r.client2, r.client1) not in (
    select s.clientFrom, s.clientObject from LibrairieBundle\Entity\SuggestClient s 
    where s.clientTo = :cible 
  )
');
```

Comment: Can you show us the doctrine code where you have this query?

Comment: of course, well the objectif is to retrieve my friends and suggest them to a friend. and the list shouldn't contain friends that i already suggested them to my friend xD it's complecated a little bit $query = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT r FROM LibrairieBundle\Entity\Reseau r WHERE ( r.client1 = :me or r.client2 = :me ) and r.confirme = 1 and (r.client2, r.client1) not in (select s.clientFrom, s.clientObject from LibrairieBundle\Entity\SuggestClient s where s.clientTo = :cible )');

Comment: When you use exactly the code from your comment, what query is generated?

Answer (score 1):

Separate the where clause.

```
SELECT 
    e 
FROM 
    \Entity e 
WHERE 
    e.field1 NOT IN (SELECT e2.field1 FROM \Entity e2 WHERE condition ) AND
    e.field2 NOT IN (SELECT e3.field2 FROM \Entity e3 WHERE condition )
```

Comment: thank you ihsan for the answer, i already tried that yesterday but i had an error message telling me that alias e2 is duplicated or something like that :/